# Dojo class event listener disappears upon subsequent instantiation

Tags: events, dojo

I have a simple class called Draggable, which has a Moveable and a click event listener:

```
define([
'dojo/dom',
'dojo/query',
'dojo/dom-style',
'dojo/dnd/Moveable',
'dojo/_base/declare'
], function(
dom,
query,
domStyle,
Moveable,
declare
){
return declare(null, {
    constructor: function(id){
        this.id = id;
        dom.byId('draggables').innerHTML +=
            '<div id="' + id + '" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; border: 1px solid #000;"></div>';
        this.moveable = new Moveable(id, {
            handle: dom.byId(id)
        });
        query('#' + id).on('click', function(){ console.log(id); });
    }
});
});
```

In the main HTML file, index.html, I simply create two instances of Draggable, A and B:

```
<script>
require([
'dojo',
'dojo/query',
'extras/Draggable'
], function(
query,
Draggable
){
var a = new Draggable('A');
var b = new Draggable('B');
});
</script>
```

If I created Draggable A alone (without creating Draggable B), I can drag Draggable A around, and whenever I click on it, the console will log "A" as expected.

However, once I create Draggables A and B (as shown in the code), only Draggable B can be dragged around, and only when I click on Draggable B will the console log "B". It seems as though the moment Draggable B is created, Draggable A loses both its Moveable and its event listener!

Comment: Do you intentionnaly avoid creating templated widget? What are you trying to achieve with your class?

Comment: This is a simplified version of the problem I am facing. I am going to try doing a widget, but for now I am worried about why an object will lose its listener if another object of the same class is created. Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you'd better go another way. Movable class designed so you can't use it as mixin in your widget. It's constructor requires a node as parameter and templated widget don't have node at this moment, except srcNodeRef, if it was passed.

So, I'd suggest you do the following:

**1** Create templated widget without Movable class. Attach your event listeners, if you need. It will work out of the box without any collisions if you properly use data-dojo-attach-event attribute or any other way you like.
Code of widget may look like:

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dijit/_WidgetBase",
    "dijit/_TemplatedMixin"
], function (
    declare,
    _WidgetBase,
    _TemplatedMixin
) {
    "use strict";
    return declare("Draggable", [_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin], {
        templateString: "<div data-dojo-attach-event='click: clickHandler' style='width: 100px; height: 100px; border: 1px solid #000'>draggable div</div>",
        clickHandler: function (e) {
            console.log("Clicked:", this.id, e);
        }
    });
});
```

**2** Somewhere in your page you'll create your widgets and make them movable like:

```
    <script>
        require(["dojo/dnd/Moveable", "Draggable"], function (Movable, Draggable){
            let d1 = new Draggable();
            d1.placeAt("myContainer");

            let d2 = new Draggable();
            d2.placeAt("myContainer");

            let m1 = new Movable(d1.domNode);
            let m2 = new Movable(d2.domNode);

        });
    </script>

    <div id="myContainer"></div>
```

I've tested, it worked for me. Hope it'll help;